# python3 importing from package on linux for tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm having this directory structure:

```
MyPackage/  
----/ __init__.py  

----/ tests / __init__.py  
----/ tests / test_file.py

----/ src /  
----/ src / __init__.py  
----/ src / file.py
```

in test_file.py I have tried:

```
from ..src.file import MyClass
from MyPackage.src.file import MyClass
```

I'm trying to run test_file.py from within the tests folder, like this:

```
python3 test_file.py
```

But any way I try it, it doesn't work:

"No module named MyPackage" (for "MyPackage.src.file")

"Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import" (if I use "..src.file")

Can anybody please tell me What the problem is and what can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually add the module basedir to the PYTHONPATH using sys.path.append()

```
import os
import sys

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PACKAGE_DIR = SCRIPT_DIR + '/..'
sys.path.append(PACKAGE_DIR)

from src.file import MyClass
```

EDIT: If you always execute from the package basedir..

```
$ cd MyPackage
$ python tests/test_file.py
```

..the package basedir should be included in your PYTHONPATH and import should work like this

```
from src.file import MyClass
```

I've had problems on some systems, where the current directory was not added automatically added to PYTHONPATH. Explicitly setting PYTHONPATH helped

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python tests/test_file.py
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I have also just found out that I can export PYTHONPATH in terminal, and then I can run python3 test_<name>.py. This is useful, since I actually have a bunch of test files.